# how to set background image of a div whose value is coming from a dialog(image url) in sightly component AEM?

Tags: html, aem

I am working on a sightly component using AEM 6.1. I have a dialog from where I am getting an image url and I want to set that image as background of a div.

What I am doing is:

```
<div class="hero" style= "background-image:url('/content/dam/home/hero.jpg');" >
```

So, `/content/dam/home/hero.jpg` value is coming as dialog property

I am trying as..

```
<div class="hero" style= "background-image:url('${properties.bgimage}');" >
```

Its not working. How can I set the background image from the dialog property?

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error? How does the rendered HTML look like? Does it contain a path (the rendered HTML) within `url('')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sightly doesn't detect the context of expressions within style and scripts automatically. We need to provide it explicity.

```
<div class="hero" style="background-image:url('${properties.bgimage @ context='styleString'}');" >
```

[More about Display Context here.](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context)

Answer (score 2):

@context='uri' would also be an option, since it's technically a URI that the css property is expecting.

Comment: This also allowed for the http:// in the url which was being parsed into "\2f\2f" for me. Thanks